Dragable list with expandable input items
I am creating a web app that needs the following feature:
Creating an ordered list of items.
Each item has several inputs:

Geolocation or list of geolocations
Several dropbox items
Several free text inputs (single line short inputs)

There are about 4 different item types (templates) and the overall list can be a mix and match of those templates.
I am looking for the simplest React components to create this component. My site will be based on prime react components so I was hoping to find components from that library.
I was looking into using elements such as datatable, orderlist and accordion from prime react but am not sure if that is the best way about it. Especially the part where there are input components involved.
Also looked into React beautiful DND but it seems to be out of support.

you can use dnd-kit https://dndkit.com/
